# TFS permissions for Work Items

Tags: windows, security, permissions, team-foundation-server

I've just created a new TFS project. Than team members have been added as project *Contributors*. However, a user (team members) doesn't have any access to the *Work Items*. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions for work items are based on the areas/iterations where they occur, and are set through the dialogue that defines areas an iterations. See Team Explorer | *right click project* | Team Project Settings | Arreas and Iterations... | *Select node* | Security...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms252587